# How to resolve hardhat solidity-coverage error: Could not instrument

Tags: solidity, hardhat, solidity-coverage

When I'm trying to use the plugin solidity-coverage (in hardhat), it returns the following error:
`Error in plugin solidity-coverage: TypeError: Could not instrument: libraries\BigNumber.sol. (Please verify solc can compile this file without errors.) Cannot read properties of null (reading 'identifier_list')`

The plugin manages to instrument my other files, and the overall application compile and work as expected, including the BigNumber.sol library that seems to be the problem here. All my tests works, including test of contracts that uses this library. [Here is the link to this file](https://github.com/CryptolygonIdle/Cryptolygon-Smart-Contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/BigNumber.sol), if it helps.

I've tried:

- Deleting node_modules folder and reinstalling dependencies
- Uninstalling/Installing solidity-coverage
- Going to the latest version of solidity-coverage

I've also tried to use a solidity-coverage config file to skip the problematic file, but it didn't seems to take it into account and gave the same error. Also, because I use this library in most of my other files, I cannot really test if it works without this library. I'm currently trying to find the problem with this particular library, if it is even the issue, I will keep this post updated with any findings.

Edit: I did not manage to really resolve the issue yet, but I circumvented it by ignoring the problematic file. To do so, yo `.solcover.js` file in the root of your project, and add the files/folders you want to ignore like this:

```
module.exports = {
    skipFiles: ['libraries']
  };
```

Then, run `npx hardhat clean` and the changes should be taken into account.

Check [the plugin's README](https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage) for details